# Htaccess request_uri relative path

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

i've got a problem.

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /metin_cms/
RewriteRule !^(no_page|paypal|paygol|client|comm|ajax|stats|news|data|it|admin|index\.php|board|resources|style\.css) /metin_cms/it%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,NE,QSA,B]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,NE,QSA,B]
```

This htaccess redirects urls like site.com/content to site.com/it/content
I changed the software directory(htaccess too) and now urls like site.com/metin_cms/test redirects to site.com/metin_cms/it/metin_cms/test because the %{REQUEST_URI} is /metin_cms/test

There is any way to "remove" from request_uri the /metin_cms/ segment?